# Cannot understand the Output of this Code

Tags: c, recursion

```
void abc(int n) {
    if (n <= 10) {
        abc(++n);
        printf("%d\n", n);
    }
}

void main() {
    int m = 5;
    abc(m);
}
```

The output shows:

```
11
10
9
8
7
6
```

I cannot understand the output. Please explain. I am a novice code lover.

Comment: Go through what the code does by writing it down on paper and/or step through it using a debugger

Comment: Also `void main()` is not standard C - it should be `int main(void)` (see: http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/main_function)

Comment: @TanmoyMukherjee: you can accept one of the answers by clicking on the grey checkmark below its score.

Answer (score 2):

The sequence of events is this:

- `main` calls `abc(5)`.
- `abc(5)`: `n` is `<= 10`, hence `n` is incremented to `6`, calling `abc(6)`.
- `abc(6)`: `n` is `<= 10`, hence `n` is incremented to `7`, calling `abc(7)`.
- `abc(7)`: `n` is `<= 10`, hence `n` is incremented to `8`, calling `abc(8)`.
- `abc(8)`: `n` is `<= 10`, hence `n` is incremented to `9`, calling `abc(9)`.
- `abc(9)`: `n` is `<= 10`, hence `n` is incremented to `10`, calling `abc(10)`.
- `abc(10)`: `n` is `<= 10`, hence `n` is incremented to `11`, calling `abc(11)`.
- `abc(11)`: `n` is not `<= 10`, function returns without any output.
- back to `abc(10)`: its own `n` variable is still `11`, `printf` prints `11`, function returns.
- back to `abc(9)`: its own `n` variable is still `10`, `printf` prints `10`, function returns.
- back to `abc(8)`: its own `n` variable is still `9`, `printf` prints `9`, function returns.
- back to `abc(7)`: its own `n` variable is still `8`, `printf` prints `8`, function returns.
- back to `abc(6)`: its own `n` variable is still `7`, `printf` prints `7`, function returns.
- back to `abc(5)`: its own `n` variable is still `6`, `printf` prints `6`, function returns.
- `main` returns

Complete output:

```
11
10
9
8
7
6
```

Each instance of `abc()` has its own value for local variable `n`, which explains why the values printed by the different instances are different.

Note that you should also:

- include `<stdio.h>`
- define `main` with this prototype: `int main(void)`
- for good style, add a `return 0;` statement at the end of `main`.

Answer (score 0):

```
void abc(int n)
{
   if (n<=10)
   {
      abc(++n);
      printf("%d\n",n);
   }
}

void main()
{
   int m=5;
   abc(m);
}
```

When `main` is called, a variable `m` is initialized to `5`.

`abc` is then called and the `5` is passed to it.

When `abc` first executes, `n = 5`. If `n` is less than or greater than 10, `abc` is called again but this time with `1+n`. Therefore, since `5` is less than 10, `abc` is called and `6` is passed to it.

Comment: *"`printf("%d\n",n);` will never be called"*?? What? Of course it will be called. Did you run this code?

Comment: @UnholySheep Woops. Updated. No, I did not run the code.

Comment: *"This repeats until `n <= 10`, at which point, the program stops."* is still wrong, the program doesn't just stop when `n` is bigger than 10. That's not how recursion works.

Comment: @UnholySheep Happy now? Also, could you please explain what would happen when n > 10?

Comment: @pookie-- if n > 10 the function returns to the caller; so when `n` has been incremented to 11 `abc()` returns to the previous call, `abc(10)`, and executes the `printf()`, printing `11`, then returning to the previous call, etc....

Comment: @DavidBowling Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

To make the function clear exclude the recursive code of it itself the following way

```
void abc(int n)
{
if (n<=10){
    ++n;
    printf("%d\n",n);
    }
}
```

So if the function is called with argument equal to 5 then the function outputs 6. If the function is called with argument equal to 10 then the function outputs 11 due to the expression statement

```
++n;
```

Now just add the recursive call the following way

```
void abc(int n)
{
if (n<=10)
    ++n;
    {abc( n);
    printf("%d\n",n);
    }
}
```

and you will get the described result.

Take into account that according to the C Standard the function main shall be declared like

```
int main( void )
```

Comment: Thanx.  I cant understand why the code prints 11 then 10 then 9 ...in this decrementing order.

Comment: Missing brace in the first example, bad indentation and formatting on the second.

Comment: @chqrlie Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would first suggest you to read basics of recursion. It will be good for you.

Now about All the recursive calling, it will be like as bellow:

> abc(5);

This will call the function abc with value 5.
Now before printing it, it will make the recursive call to abc but before calling it will increment the value of n from 5 to 6. The same will happen in the next call from 6 to 7, 7 to 8, 8 to 9, 9 to 10 and 10 to 11. Now on the call for n=11, the if condition will fail and recursion will stop. On returning from recursive calls, it will print increment values but from last call to first,i.e. for 11 than 10 and so on till 6.

Comment: Thankx a lot for answering.The point that was not clear to me is that why the incremented values are printed from last to first ... is it due to the fact that the intermediate values are stored on stack and popped out from top or what?

Comment: Running the function abc(5) will be like:
if (n<=10)  // n = 5 so condition is true
   {
      abc(++n);  // value of n will be incremented to 6 and the function will be called
      printf("%d\n",n); // the value 6 will be printed.
   }
Not it will go like:

abc(6);
  abc(7);
    abc(8);
       abc(9);
          abc(10);
            abc(11); // recursion stops here
               if(11<=10)  // fails
            print(11);
          print(10);
        print(9);
      print(8);
    print(7);
  print(6);

Answer (score 0):

First off in these lines of code, what is the output?

```
printf("7\n");
printf("6\n");
```

If you guess `7` before `6` you are correct. If you call two functions that prints something, the one called first will output first. This is **very important**

Lets first rewrite your function so that each line doesn't do separate things. I'm thinking of the mutating `++n`:

```
void abc(int n) {
    if (n <= 10) {
        n = n + 1;
        abc(n);
        printf("%d\n", n);
    }
}
```

So if you pass `9` to this it will first change `n` to `10`, then call `abc(10)` and get the output of that **before** it prints `10`. The call to `abc(10)` increases its `n` to `11` and calls `abc(11)` first, which doesn't do anything, then does its `printf` `"11\n"` and returns to the call where `n` is `10` and do its `printf` `"10\n"` before it returns to the initial call.

The output is:

```
11
10
```

If you do `abc(5)` it works the same. `abc(6)` needs to output first. And in `abc(6)` `abc(7)` needs to output first all the way to `11` thet doesn' have output and then it goes back, prints `11`, `10`, .... `n + 1`.

## You can do it the other way around!

Lets say you start at the base case `abc(11)` and see the code doesn't do anything.

Then you look at `abc(10)`. You see it will first increase `n` to `11`, then call `abc(11)` which we previously saw does nothing and then it prints `n`, thus `11`. Thus `abc(10)` prints `"11\n"`.

If you look at `abc(9)` you see that `n` increases to `10`, then it calls `abc(10)`. You already know that that it prints `"11\n"`, then it does its `printf` adding `"10\n" to the output, thus:

```
11
10
```

Now if you do this with one number lower you eventually get to `abc(5)`.. It increases `n` to `6`, then calls `abc(6)` which you know outputs `"11\n10\n9\n8\n7\n"` and then it does the next line that prints `"6\n"` making the output of `abc(5)` `"11\n10\n9\n8\n7\n6\n"`

Comment: Thank you everyone. Now it is clear. You helped a lot to learn coding to a novice.